# Image fusion using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have fuse two images in Matlab but there is a lot of transparency between them as you can see in the picture. [image]

How can I make the person more visible by cutting down the transparency? I am using Matlab's `imfuse(A,B,'blend')`?

Comment: Not sure if thats possible with `imfuse`, but https://ch.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/image-overlay-using-transparency.html seems to cover it with other means.